# Download under user's profile directory

Tags: python

I have a hard time placing the file I have just downloaded in any other folder than the one the script is in. It really wouldn't matter but I am trying to remotely update some programs with ninite. I am able to download the file but only to the folder the the script is in. I need to run the nininte.exe after its been downloaded with a few command line arguments (namely silent) that I was going to pass to it with a batch script. I would like to just dump it in the downloads folder. When I google it I just get hits on installing python to a specific folder.

Here is my code so far

```
import urllib

ninite = urllib.urlopen("www.downloadSite.com")
localFile = open('ninite.exe', 'wb')
localFile.write(ninite.read())
ninite.close()
```

The script works great like this but when I try to add the folder location `localFile = open('%userprofile%/Downloads/ninite', 'wb')` it returns an error that there's no file or directory with that name.

Comment: Probably you need to [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) first. Also `%userprofile` looks suspicious.

Comment: Don't use `file1.write(file2.read())`. Use something like [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) or one of [`shutil`'s copy functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html).

Comment: `os.rename()` will not work if source and destination are on different filesystems. `shutil` should be fine, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`os.path.expandvars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) to expand environment variables such as `%userprofile%` in the destination directory name and use [`urllib.urlretrieve()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) to download the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import urllib

url = "https://example.com/path" # where to get the file from
dest_dir = os.path.expandvars('%userprofile%/Downloads/ninite') # where to put it

# make the directories (recursively)
try:
    os.makedirs(dest_dir)
except OSError: # ignore errors
    pass

# download the file
urllib.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join(dest_dir, 'ninite.exe'))
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use the Windows equivalent of `~/Downloads/ninite`. The [os.path.expanduser()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) library function will help you here. You can do this:

```
import os.path
os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/ninite.exe')
```

That will return the full path to the file. Although the tilde is a Unix thing, on Windows it will substitute your `%userprofile%` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want to use is `%userprofile%` which is an environment variable on Windows. `open()` would not expand it and would treat it literally. You should use os.environ('userprofile') to retrieve the path stored in the environment variable and use it to construct full path to the file. Something like this should do the trick:

```
localFile = open(os.environ['USERPROFILE']+'/ninite.exe', 'wb')
```

Comment: I think This is on the right track for what I'm looking for. But now when I run my script I get _Environ instance has no __call__ method. A little lost on that error?

Comment: @user3335541: replace `()` with `[]`: `value = os.environ['envvar']`

Comment: You could also replace `+` with [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).